# Devise sign_up ignores remember_me value

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm just getting started with Devise. I have a:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end
```

and I've altered my sign_up view to:

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><%= f.email_field :email %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :contact_me %><%= f.check_box :contact_me %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :remember_me %><%= f.check_box :remember_me %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render :partial => "devise/shared/links" %>
```

However, checking the POST response, I can see the `remember_user_token` set in `Cookie:` after sign-up whether I ticked "Remember me" or not. Anyone know why that is, and how to stop it?

By comparison, signing *in* only sets that cookie if the box is ticked, as expected.

Comment: @Ashitaka - I'm not sure, actually. I'll try to have a check for you when I get a moment. Might not be that soon, though.

Answer (score 1):

I now that you are using for_for, but i use form_tag... Such code works on my project:

```
.form
  = form_tag new_user_session_path do  
    = email_field_tag 'user[email]', nil, :placeholder => "Ваш e-mail", :required => true
    = password_field_tag 'user[password]', nil, :placeholder => "Ваш пароль", :required => true
    .submit-area
        = submit_tag "Вход", :class => "orange-button"
        = check_box_tag 'user[remember_me]', true
        .login-link
          Запомнить меня
```

So that part will work fine:

```
= check_box_tag 'user[remember_me]', true
```

Comment: I wanted to shoot you an quick comment to look over an answer I provided on your question here: http://superuser.com/questions/558660/imagemagick-batch-converting-memory-overload/1126572#1126572 in case you find it helpful... +1